# Is there a plugin to connect Visual Studio 2010 to Mantis BugTracker?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, integration, mantis

I have MantisBT installed in my server and I want to connect it to Visual Studio 2010 to manage issues in my projects.

Is there any plugin to do this (softly...)?

**Edit**

I've found AnkhMantisConnector, but this tool not works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [AnkhMantisConnector](https://code.google.com/p/ankhmantisconnector).

It's from June/2012, but I hope it works fine.